# When creating user roles, should I create 3 tables, users-users_roles-roles or should I just create a role column in the users table?

Tags: mysql

In my previous project, I had a users table that had a role column which had an integer inside. By default, the integer that would be written inside the column when a user registers was 2, which meant he was a normal user. If the number was 1, it meant the user is an admin.

Now I can only assume that this is a really stupid execution of user roles. The other way I can think of is using 3 tables, users, users_roles and roles.

Is this the better way of accomplishing this task?

Comment: This is a requirements led decision - Can a user ever have more than 1 role?

Comment: Well so far - no. In this case, which way is the most optimal?

Comment: Define optimal - from a processing perspective, the simpler option is faster, from an extensibility perspective it is not as optimal. You do want to avoid premature optimizations though, you may be over thinking it.